# Simple PL/SQL to check if table exists is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm in the process of converting some stored procedures from Sybase TSQL to Oracle PL/SQL and I've already come across a problem which I'm struggling to resolve!

The below code will not run:

```
DECLARE

t INT := 0;
t_error EXCEPTION;
v_line VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO t FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = UPPER('tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue');

IF t = 1 THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue';
  t := 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO t FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = UPPER('tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue');
  IF t = 1 THEN
    RAISE t_error;
  END IF;
END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN t_error THEN
  v_line := '<<< FAILED DROPPING table tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue >>>';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_line);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_line := '<<< Unknown Error >>>';
    dbms_output.put_line (v_line);
  END;


END;
```

I get the following error message, what am I doing wrong?!

> Error starting at line : 17 in command - DECLARE
>
> t INT := 0; t_error EXCEPTION; v_line VARCHAR2(100);
>
> BEGIN
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO t FROM user_tables WHERE table_name =
>   UPPER('tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue');
>
> IF t = 1 THEN   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue';
>   t := 0;   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO t FROM user_tables WHERE table_name =
>   UPPER('tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue');   IF t = 1 THEN
>       RAISE t_error;   END IF; END IF;
>
> EXCEPTION   WHEN t_error THEN   v_line := '<<< FAILED DROPPING table
>   tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue >>>';   dbms_output.put_line (v_line);   WHEN
>   OTHERS THEN
>       v_line := '<<< Unknown Error >>>';
>       dbms_output.put_line (v_line);   END;
>         END; Error report - ORA-06550: line 30, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" 
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

I'm actually trying to replace the following TSQL with a PL/SQL version:

```
-- Create temp table for relevant trev_id's 
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue') IS NOT NULL
        PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING TABLE dbo.tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue >>>'
    ELSE
        PRINT '<<< DROPPED TABLE dbo.tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue >>>'
END
go
```

Comment: Do you execute it via sqlplus?

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer.

Answer (score 9):

try to remove `END;` in this section

```
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_line := '<<< Unknown Error >>>';
    dbms_output.put_line (v_line);
 END;
```

UPD. Actually, you can do it a bit shorter, no need to check if table exists after drop

```
declare
  eTableNotExists exception;
  pragma exception_init(eTableNotExists, -00942);
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue';  
    dbms_output.put_line('<<< DROPPED TABLE dbo.tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue >>>');
exception 
  when eTableNotExists then null
  when others then    
    dbms_output.put_line ('<<< Unknown Error >>>' || sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry but please see my original post ( i have added some further info at the bottom) so you can see what I'm trying to replace. Your shorter version is more elegant but I'm not sure it behaves in the same way as the TSQL version?

Comment: my version tries to drop table and if it doesn't exist it does nothing :) anyway, I glad that we solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the error, but you can do what you want in a fraction of the code. You don't need the count variable if you use `EXISTS()` and you don't need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` because you don't have variable data in the command:

```
IF 1 = (SELECT 1 FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'TBL_BSUK_PRICEISSUE') THEN
  DROP TABLE tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue;
  IF 1 = (SELECT 1 FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'TBL_BSUK_PRICEISSUE') THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION;
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Comment: I voted for this however, when I try the above code I get "invalid SQL statement"

Comment: In fact the following just won't run WTF?! IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue') THEN
 DROP TABLE tbl_BSUK_PriceIssue;
END IF;

Comment: Doesn't work for me in PL/SQL: PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only

Comment: Yep, that's definitely not PL/SQL.